# NestJs: How can I add options for my Custom Validation Pipe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I created a custom validation pipe where I want to add some custom logic.I want to know how can I extend it so that I can call it with the below options

Edited:
I have referred the below link of the github file and have developed my own pipe but there still seems to be something missing as its not validating as per the DTO
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/1f6fca5f55e9e51705fa326654760736b254f4e5/packages/common/pipes/validation.pipe.ts#L48

Comment: see how this is done with the built-in `ValidationPipe`: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/1f6fca5f55e9e51705fa326654760736b254f4e5/packages/common/pipes/validation.pipe.ts#L48

Comment: Add just a constructor ?

Comment: @MicaelLevi That link was helpful.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by creating my own pipe.

```
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException, Logger, Optional } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { ValidatorOptions, ValidationError, isObject, validate } from 'class-validator';
    import { plainToClass, classToPlain, ClassTransformOptions } from 'class-transformer';
    import { iterate } from 'iterare';
    
    
    const isUndefined = (obj: any): obj is undefined =>
        typeof obj === 'undefined';
    
    const isNil = (val: any): val is null | undefined =>
        isUndefined(val) || val === null;
    
    
    interface ValidationPipeOptions extends ValidatorOptions {
        transform?: boolean;
        transformOptions?: ClassTransformOptions;
        validateCustomDecorators?: boolean;
    }
    
    
    @Injectable()
    export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
    
        private readonly logger = new Logger(ValidationPipe.name);
        protected isTransformEnabled: boolean;
        protected transformOptions: ClassTransformOptions;
        protected validatorOptions: ValidatorOptions;
        protected validateCustomDecorators: boolean;
    
    
        constructor(@Optional() options?: ValidationPipeOptions) {
            options = options || {};
            const {
                transform,
                transformOptions,
                validateCustomDecorators,
                ...validatorOptions
            } = options;
    
    
            this.isTransformEnabled = !!transform;
            this.transformOptions = transformOptions;
            this.validatorOptions = validatorOptions;
            this.validateCustomDecorators = validateCustomDecorators || false;
        }
    
        async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    
            const metatype = metadata.metatype;
            if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metadata)) {
                return this.isTransformEnabled
                    ? this.transformPrimitive(value, metadata)
                    : value;
            }
    
            const originalValue = value;
            value = this.toEmptyIfNil(value);
    
            const isNil = value !== originalValue;
            const isPrimitive = this.isPrimitive(value);
            this.stripProtoKeys(value);
            let object = plainToClass(metatype, value, this.transformOptions);
    
            const originalEntity = object;
            const isCtorNotEqual = object.constructor !== metatype;
    
            if (isCtorNotEqual && !isPrimitive) {
                object.constructor = metatype;
            } else if (isCtorNotEqual) {
                // when "entity" is a primitive value, we have to temporarily
                // replace the entity to perform the validation against the original
                // metatype defined inside the handler
                object = { constructor: metatype };
            }
    
            const errors = await this.validate(object, this.validatorOptions);
            if (errors.length > 0) {
    
                for (let error of errors) {
                    for (let key in error.constraints) {
                        this.logger.error(`${error.target.constructor.name}:${error.constraints[key]}`);
                    }
                }
                throw new BadRequestException('Invalid Input Parameters');
            }
    
    
            if (isPrimitive) {
                // if the value is a primitive value and the validation process has been successfully completed
                // we have to revert the original value passed through the pipe
                object = originalEntity;
            }
    
            if (this.isTransformEnabled) {
                return object;
            }
    
            if (isNil) {
                // if the value was originally undefined or null, revert it back
                return originalValue;
            }
    
            return Object.keys(this.validatorOptions).length > 0
                ? classToPlain(object, this.transformOptions)
                : value;
        }
    
    
    
        protected stripProtoKeys(value: Record<string, any>) {
            delete value.__proto__;
            const keys = Object.keys(value);
            iterate(keys)
                .filter(key => isObject(value[key]) && value[key])
                .forEach(key => this.stripProtoKeys(value[key]));
        }
    
        protected isPrimitive(value: unknown): boolean {
            return ['number', 'boolean', 'string'].includes(typeof value);
        }
    
    
        protected transformPrimitive(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
            if (!metadata.data) {
                // leave top-level query/param objects unmodified
                return value;
            }
            const { type, metatype } = metadata;
            if (type !== 'param' && type !== 'query') {
                return value;
            }
            if (metatype === Boolean) {
                return value === true || value === 'true';
            }
            if (metatype === Number) {
                return +value;
            }
            return value;
        }
    
    
        protected toEmptyIfNil<T = any, R = any>(value: T): R | {} {
            return isNil(value) ? {} : value;
        }
    
        private toValidate(metadata: ArgumentMetadata): boolean {
    
            const { metatype, type } = metadata;
            if (type === 'custom' && !this.validateCustomDecorators) {
                return false;
            }
            const types = [String, Boolean, Number, Array, Object, Buffer];
            return !types.some(t => metatype === t) && !isNil(metatype);
    
        }
    
        protected validate(
            object: object,
            validatorOptions?: ValidatorOptions,
        ): Promise<ValidationError[]> | ValidationError[] {
            return validate(object, validatorOptions);
        }
    
    }
```